# Flutter:- already_active, Image picker is already active, null, null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-image

Everytime I'm pressing pick image in release mode it's showing me this error

```
E/flutter (24004): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(already_active, Image picker is already active, null, null)
E/flutter (24004): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:581)
E/flutter (24004): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158)
E/flutter (24004): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24004): #2      MethodChannelImagePicker.pickImage (package:image_picker_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_image_picker.dart:29)
E/flutter (24004): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24004): #3      _UploadDataCardState.getImage (package:visual_retail/screens/FillData/UploadDataCard.dart:164)
E/flutter (24004): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24004):
```

In debug mode it's working properly

[image: error]

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade Gradle version to : classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'

Answer (score 0):

after downgrading Gradle version change kotlin version
this is my version `ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'` for `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'`

find yours

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```